# derby server refuse connection to database with boot password

Tags: java, eclipse, jdbc, derby, dbeaver

i have derby server with database created with boot password while connecting to it in derby the connection refused. where i write my boot password as connection property.
how to write connection URL manually? or where to write boot password?

Comment: Are you asking about this: http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.12/security/cseccsecure60146.html

Comment: I am already secured my data base using boot password ant run from my application when add the boot password to connection URL but DBEAVER cant open the data base